# kubectl delete pod with deployment name

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I often sometimes my pods for debugging with `kubectl delete pod`, so it updates the container image. But every time I have to lookup
the complete name of the pod:

```
kubectl delete pod deployment_name-56fccbbfb8g4rj6
```

How can I just delete the pod without knowing the hash?

Comment: You shouldn't need to manually delete anything to update the image; just change the `image:` tag in the containing deployment spec, and it will automatically replace the pods with new ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can delete the pod based on the labels. For example, if your pod has label `app=alpine`, you can delete it like this:

```
kubectl delete pod -l app=alpine
```

Comment: what does the `-nxxx` do?

Comment: It's short for --namespace your_namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your shell, you can use [auto completion](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#enabling-shell-autocompletion) to have your pod name suggested by the system.

- **Bash**-completion is provided by many package managers (see [here](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion#installation)). You
  can install it with `apt-get install bash-completion` or `yum install bash-completion`, etc.
- For **Zsh** this can be generated with the command  `kubectl    completion zsh`. Sourcing the completion script in your shell enables
  kubectl autocompletion.

  To do so in all your shell sessions, add the following to your  `~/.zshrc`  file:

  ```
  source <(kubectl completion zsh)
  ```

---

Another thing is that you don't need to destroy your pod to update your image. You can simply use [kubectl patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#patch/) or  `kubectl set image`.

For more reading please check Kubernetes document about patching the [API objects with kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/).

Answer (score 0):

- delete pods / namesapces

kubectl get pod --all-namespaces | grep -viE "compl|running" | awk 'NR>1{print $2 " -n " $1}' |while read line;do kubectl delete pod $line;done

Answer (score -2):

that's not possible but you can delete all of them at once using kubectl here:

```
kubectl delete --all pods --namespace=foo
```

if you want to delete a single pod you have to do it manually. else try this solution.